# Relative 3D rotation from an homography matrix

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

I want to obtain a relative 3D rotation from the homography between two images.
A way of doing this would be decomposing the homography matrix (maybe using opencv **decomposeHomographyMat**) . However, I want to do this with an uncalibrated camera (no intrinsics matrix to use in the homography decomposition). Also, I'm interested in the general case of any rigid transformation between the cameras that took the images, not necessarily a pure rotation.

Is this possible at all? any references? it feels to me there should be some way of obtaining at least an estimate of this relative rotation without the intrinsics matrix.

Answer (score 2):

decomposeHomographyMat produces a rotation and a (scale-free) translation - and a normal, times four possible solutions.

If your setup is uncalibrated, but you can make a decent guess as to the focal length, you can start by solving for the essential matrix, decompose it and then just bundle adjust. If not, all you can get is a projective recon.

References: the Hartley and Zisserman book is  good start.

Comment: I was hoping of a way of getting this relative rotation directly from the homography matrix without having to go back to the data used to obtain the homography.

Comment: You can in the calibrated (even approximately calibrated) case. Just guesstimate a focal length and use the image center as your principal point.